# beautifulsoup: how to give value to empty nodes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was wondering if it's possible to give a value to a empty node.

Original: `<td></td>`
Want to change to: `<td>anything</td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find the node using

```
node = soup.find("td")
```

then you may provide content to this element by assigning to `node.string`:

```
node.string = "anything"
```

Full example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                                                   

soup = BeautifulSoup('<td></td>')                                                
node = soup.find("td")                                                          
node.string = "anything"                                                        
print(soup)
```

Output:

```html
<html><body><td>anything</td></body></html>
```

If you have many such nodes, and only want to assign to the empty ones, you may do something like:

```
for node in soup.find_all("td"):
    if not node.string:
        node.string = "anything"
```

Comment: One more thing if I used "find_all('td')" and then I have a list, is it possible to give a custom value to only empty node? Example:
<td>something</td>
<td></td> give a value "something"
<td>something</td>

Comment: Changed your code a bit if not node.string or node.string == ' ': and now everything is perfect, thank you!